# Wordpress ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a small question for you. How can I dinamicaly get a plugin file path? I want to make an ajax call from a page to a file wich is in my plugins directory, and I don't want to use wp-content/ . . . . etc Is there a way to do that? So it can work on every site. Thank you

Comment: Don't do that. Wordpress says you should route AJAX calls through `admin-ajax.php`, and they publish the documented way to do that in the codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins   If you do not follow this advice, you will likely have problems on non-standard installations of Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you looking for:

```
$plugin_url =WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/'.dirname(plugin_basename (__FILE__));
```

this must be placed in your plugin file.